# How can I make new heading tag numbers, such as h7, h8, etc.?

Tags: html

How can I make another heading in HTML?

I have used <h1>, <h2>, <h3>, <h4>, <h5> and <h6>, and now I would like to add <h7> and <h8> as I have different text types that I need to use.

If you cannot do this, is there a way to call upon CSS sheets for text, other than <p> and <h1> - <h6>?

Comment: You could use the css property "font-size", "font-size:10;font-size:12;..."

Comment: What is the use case for headings at more than six levels? There might be a better approach.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela when writing a technical book, it is easy to go beyond 6.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can declare this in your style sheet:

```css
h7, h8, h9 { /* You can just go on adding headings */
   display: block; /* Because this is a block level element */
}

h7 {
   font-size: /* Whatever */ ;
}

h8 {
   font-size: /* Whatever */ ;
}
```

But I would suggest you not to do so, as it doesn't carry any semantic meaning. Also it will be bad from a [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) point of view.

Also take a look at [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/). Just add the elements you want in the script.

Comment: And how will this help me? I need to add a heading 7 or an alternative to call upon the css.

Comment: @Stonydallas I didnt got you how it will help you means? If you are asking while keeping standards in mind, than you shouldn't use this

Comment: Then how will i call upon css to style the text?

Comment: @Stonydallas just add styles in the respective element like `h9 {/* styles goes here */} h10 {/* styles goes here */}`

Comment: Thanks that works! I had done that before but with know result, now it works

Comment: @Stonydallas But I will suggest you not to use this

Comment: OK I will just make the 6 last, maybe just not use so many Google fonts :)

Comment: @Stonydallas you can use something like `<h2><span class="fsize"></span></h2>` and use `h2 span.customh2 {/*Styles goes here*/}`

Comment: I disagree with your commentary in your post. "it doesn't carry any semantic meaning" it carries as much semantic meaning as span, p, and div. "it will be bad from SEO point of view" it will be no worse for SEO than span, p, div, li.

Comment: @ChrisMarisic *I would suggest you not to do so, as it doesn't carry any semantic meaning*, its for the new tags he will create, so if he creates h7, h8, will have no semantic meaning also no importance as far as SEO is concerned

Comment: Seeing as SEO is all voodoo and proprietary algorithms it's all black box guessing, but i would strongly bet that there is next to no difference between H6 and p given by search engines. What's more important is the semantic meaning of the author. Aside from properly using meta tags, H1, H2, the semantic domain value of the page far exceeds everything else. If you have H7-H10 in your domain it's pretty ridiculous to do H6.h7, H6.h10. This isn't 2008 and HTML4 any more.

Comment: To ensure the semantics are explicit, use `aria-level="7"` (or whatever). If you're using this attribute with anything other than `h1`-`h6` you will also need to add `role="heading"`. This is all valid html. BUT I would question why you need more than 6 levels of content 'depth' in the first place.

Answer (score 9):

None of the answers posted so far are quite correct. Some are quite misleading.

In [HTML5](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5), you can indeed use `h7`, `h8` and so on, and select them with corresponding CSS selectors, but semantically speaking **these are not headings**. They're just elements with unknown semantics—much like *divs* and *spans*. Also I'd be surprised if all browsers treated these 'custom' elements consistently without providing a CSS value for `display` at least.

But you **can** specify the missing semantics with a `role` attribute of `"heading"`, and this will be important for assistive technology such as screen readers. It might (conceivably) affect [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) somewhat, but there are many far bigger SEO issues than this.

The correct way to specify a heading level higher than 6 is to include the attribute `aria-level="7"` (or whatever level you prefer). If you apply this attribute to anything other than `h1`-`h6` you will also need `role="heading"`.

Therefore any of the following "h7" examples are valid and correct according to [w3](https://www.w3.org/WAI/GL/wiki/Using_role%3Dheading):

`<h1 aria-level="7">...` (heading semantics provided by "h1", but 7 overrides 1)

`<h7 role="heading" aria-level="7">...` (heading semantics provided by `role`)

`<div role="heading" aria-level="7">...` (heading semantics provided by `role`)

And of course to select any of these in CSS you could do something like:

```
*[aria-level="7"] {
    font-size:0.5em;
}
```

Finally: Don't nest headings of different levels inside each other! This is known to confuse all screen readers, and probably not valid HTML either. Close each heading element completely before starting a new one. It's easy to overlook this if you are using `div`, and validators will most likely not notice the error.

Comment: Just a FYI, the ARIA working group is considering formally deprecating `aria-level` greater than 9 for headings. (Note: `aria-level` is also used in nested lists and tables, and these will continue to permit any integer above zero). If you have strong opinions about this, you can add them to the thread at https://github.com/w3c/aria/issues/1757

Answer (score 3):

On another of my questions, which was completely unrelated, I received an answer to this question:

---

You can't make a heading 7, because there's only six different HTML headings (h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 and h6; reference: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_hn.asp), but you can make a heading 6 with this CSS code:

```
h6.special { color:#464646; outline:0;
    font-family:Raleway, sans-serif; font-size:17px; }
```

and this HTML code:

```
<h6 class="special">I am special!</h6>
```

---

---

This solution does not damage [SEO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_optimization) and is fairly simple.

I just thought I should let everyone know.

As a side question, can you change the "special"?
Say if I changed it to

```
h6.raleway { color:#464646; outline:0;
    font-family:Raleway, sans-serif; font-size:17px; }
```

and this HTML code:

```
<h6 class="raleway">I am raleway!</h6>
```

Would this work?

Comment: "You can't make a heading 7" is entirely false as long as your document type is `<!DOCTYPE html>` for HTML5. Contrary to other false statements using H7 is not going to hurt SEO, but yes using the CSS for `h6.raleway` is an alternative. This is probably a superior solution if the only purpose is to vary the font face. If your purpose is you have semantic meaning to differentiate H7 to be lesser than H6, use H7.

Comment: Re *"raleway"*: Do you mean *"[railway](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/railway#Noun)"*?

Answer (score 2):

h7, h8, h9 are not a valid HTML tags, and the browser can do what it wants with it. You can create your own CSS class and use CSS property like h2, h3, etc.

**Like:**

```css
h7{
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.51em;
    -webkit-margin-before: 2.99em;
    -webkit-margin-after: 2.99em;
    -webkit-margin-start: 0px;
    -webkit-margin-end: 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Yes but if i declare them = `h7 {font-size:50px}`

Comment: It is perfectly valid for HTML5 (as a custom element). OP does not specify HTML4 or XHTML. With XHTML I believe it would be valid if you provided your own DTD, might be applicable to HTML4 too.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way will be to use classes:

```css
.h7{ font-size: 10px;}
.h8{ font-size: 7px;}
```

Something like that way and use it with *spans* and *divs*.

Answer (score 1):

If you really need headings below the 6th level (which means that your document corresponds to a large book in structure and nesting of sections), use `div` elements with `class` attributes. (Using “custom tags” like `h7` does not conform to specifications, causes problems in IE, and creates an illusion of using headings – they won’t be headings, to search engines, outline construction, etc.) Example:

```
<style>
.h7 { font-weight: bold; margin-top: 1em; }
</style>

<div class=h7>Some text</div>
```

(It will be difficult to style headings at 7 or 8 levels so that the level is clearly reflected in the appearance and the font sizes of topmost levels are not excessively huge.)

In theory, you could use the HTML5 `section` elements to define the nesting structure of parts, chapters, sections, subsections, etc. in the document and just e.g. `h1` heading inside each `section`. By the HTML5 CR, the nesting of `section` elements then defines the levels of headings, so at the 7th level of nesting, `<h1>` would be a 7th level heading. But even to people who generally favor HTML5, this might be rather confusing, and to make this work in old versions on IE, you would need `<script>document.createElement('section')</script> as well as`section{display:block}` plus code that formats the headings using contextual selectors.

The formulation “different text types that I need to use” suggests that you might be looking for just possibilities for styling elements. In that case, use `div` or `p` or some other elements, with `class` attributes as needed, as suitable for the content and structure, and do the styling in CSS.

Comment: H7 is a perfectly valid as a HTML5 element. If the OP has semantic meaning for H7 in their domain, that is a far better solution than `.h7`

Comment: @ChrisMarisic, where do you see `H7` in HTML5? Not where it should be if it existed: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/sections.html#the-h1,-h2,-h3,-h4,-h5,-and-h6-elements