# @font-face doesn't work anymore (was fine yesterday!)

Tags: css, fonts

I have a weird problem with `@font-face` in my CSS file. It is new to me, and I used it for the first time yesterday. It worked well. Then I tried to add another `@font-face` for a different font today (without making any changes to the first one), but not only did the new font not work, it also "undid" the first font, so none of them was working. I took out everything I had added for the new font, and even deleted the files I had added to the folder, so everything is as it was before - but I can't get the first font to work again! I checked everything many times, but I can't find the problem. I'm using Firefox, but it doesn't work in IE either. Everything is only on my computer, not online.

The code and the files are from Font Squirrel (I only changed the file path). Here's what I have:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'moonstarregular';
    src: url('../fonts/moonstar-webfont.eot');
    src: url('../fonts/moonstar-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
         url('../fonts/moonstar-webfont.woff2') format('woff2'),
         url('../fonts/moonstar-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
         url('../fonts/moonstar-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
         url('../fonts/moonstar-webfont.svg#moonstarregular') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

and then:

```
h7 {
    font-weight: 600; 
    font-size: 46px;
    color: #B41221;
    font-family: 'moonstarregular', 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
```

As I said, it worked fine before, and all the files are still in the right directory. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `h7` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908463/how-to-make-a-new-heading-number-tag

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that. I replaced h7 with h1, but it still isn't working...

Comment: Font Squirrel demo works for you? try converting it again with some other site use this http://onlinefontconverter.com/

Comment: I just realized: putting the exact same code in a separate css file and linking to it in my html file makes it work! Can anybody explain this to me? It's great that it's working now, but I would like to understand why...

Comment: where you have added the `@font face` top bottom?

Comment: Yes, the complete @ font-face using the css file from Font Squirrel (unchanged). So it only works if I stick all the font files and the css in the same folder. When I put the fonts in my "font" folder and the css in my "css" folder and change the file path in the @ font-face, it doesn't work. It also doesn't work when I include the original @ font-face in my main css file and put all the font files in my css folder.

Comment: you're talking about having two @font-face custom fonts, you're only showing one. Please add all the details to your question so people don't have to guess at what you're doing. Ideally, write a working example using jsbin or jsfiddle or something so that people can suggest concrete fixes