# Is tagname violation okay?

Tags: html, css

I have a question about tagname violation.
Here's an example:

```
Jade:
    h8 HELLOVENUS

Sass:
    h8
      text-color: red
      font-size: 20px
```

Everything seems to be fine in Opera right now.. But is there any error I will face in the future? (Like different browsers gonna act strangely..)
Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908463/how-to-make-a-new-heading-number-tag

Comment: A recent QA on custom elements might be more interesting for closing

Comment: @SanjeevK the OP is not asking how, instead if they will face an issue in the future - which the linked question does not answer

Comment: OP - I suggest you elaborate a bit more on your question to stop close votes

Comment: @CalvT There's no close vote for now. But the question could clearly be better worded, for example asking about the validity of this custom element declaration;

Comment: @DenysSéguret or dupes then - and I meant votes in the near future :)

Comment: Thank you guys, i did not know the right keyword for the search. Thank you very much! :)

Comment: So to answer the question, yes, there will be problems in the future. Just like everybody who ever used <template>, <picture>, <video>, <slot>, <dialog> etc for custom elements in the past can tell you. Don't. Just don't. Or if you must, use a name with a hyphen in it.