# Is it possible to use header levels higher than h6 in github markdown? What solutions allowing deeper levels of heading?

Tags: html, github, markdown, anchor, html-heading

Is it possible to use header levels higher than 6 in github markdown?
Rending does not work for lines like `####### Some Heading`

It doesn't look like github posts their allowed tags anymore, but I see historical references to allowing `<h7>` and `<h8>` in.
My code is generating a readme file with this content:

```
<a name="top"></a>
# **inline_composition**
<a name="inline_composition"></a>

## Table of Contents
- [Summary](#summary)
- [Arguments](#arguments)
- [Return Types](#return-types)

## Summary
testing composed schemas at inline locations

## Arguments

Name | Type | Description  | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[body](#request_body) | typing.Union[[RequestBody.content.application_json.schema](#request_bodycontentapplication_jsonschema), [RequestBody.content.multipart_form_data.schema](#request_bodycontentmultipart_form_dataschema), Unset] | optional, default is unset |
[query_params](#requestqueryparameters) | [RequestQueryParameters.Params](#RequestQueryParametersParams) | |
content_type | str | optional, default is 'application/json' | Selects the schema and serialization of the request body
accept_content_types | typing.Tuple[str] | default is ("application/json", "multipart/form-data", ) | Tells the server the content type(s) that are accepted by the client
stream | bool | default is False | if True then the response.content will be streamed and loaded from a file like object. When downloading a file, set this to True to force the code to deserialize the content to a FileSchema file
timeout | typing.Optional[typing.Union[int, typing.Tuple]] | default is None | the timeout used by the rest client
skip_deserialization | bool | default is False | when True, headers and body will be unset and an instance of api_client.ApiResponseWithoutDeserialization will be returned

### <a id="request_body" >body</a>

#### <a id="request_body_request_bodydescription" >RequestBody.description</a>
multiple content types
#### <a id="request_body_request_bodycontentapplication_jsonschema" >RequestBody.content.application_json.schema</a>

#### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader,  | frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO |  |

##### Composed Schemas (allOf/anyOf/oneOf/not)
##### allOf
Class Name | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[_0](#_0) | str,  | str,  |  |

###### _0

###### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
str,  | str,  |  |
#### <a id="request_body_request_bodycontentmultipart_form_dataschema" >RequestBody.content.multipart_form_data.schema</a>

#### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict,  | frozendict.frozendict,  |  |

##### Dictionary Keys
Key | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
**someProp** | [dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader, ](#someProp) | [frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO](#someProp) |  | [optional]
**any_string_name** | dict, frozendict.frozendict, list, tuple, decimal.Decimal, float, int, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, bool, None, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader, schemas.Schema | frozendict.frozendict, tuple, decimal.Decimal, str, bytes, BoolClass, NoneClass, FileIO | any string name can be used but the value must be the correct type | [optional]

###### someProp

###### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader,  | frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO |  |

####### Composed Schemas (allOf/anyOf/oneOf/not)
####### allOf
Class Name | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[_0](#_0) | str,  | str,  |  |

######## _0

######## Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
str,  | str,  |  |

### <a id="requestqueryparameters" >query_params</a>
#### <a id="RequestQueryParametersParams" >RequestQueryParameters.Params</a>

Key | Input Type | Description  | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
compositionAtRoot | [Parameter0.schema](#parameter_0schema) | | optional
compositionInProperty | [Parameter1.schema](#parameter_1schema) | | optional


#### Parameter0
##### <a id="parameter_0schema" >Parameter0.schema</a>

##### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader,  | frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO |  |

###### Composed Schemas (allOf/anyOf/oneOf/not)
###### allOf
Class Name | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[_0](#_0) | str,  | str,  |  |

####### _0

####### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
str,  | str,  |  |

#### Parameter1
##### <a id="parameter_1schema" >Parameter1.schema</a>

##### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict,  | frozendict.frozendict,  |  |

###### Dictionary Keys
Key | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
**someProp** | [dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader, ](#someProp) | [frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO](#someProp) |  | [optional]
**any_string_name** | dict, frozendict.frozendict, list, tuple, decimal.Decimal, float, int, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, bool, None, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader, schemas.Schema | frozendict.frozendict, tuple, decimal.Decimal, str, bytes, BoolClass, NoneClass, FileIO | any string name can be used but the value must be the correct type | [optional]

####### someProp

####### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader,  | frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO |  |

######## Composed Schemas (allOf/anyOf/oneOf/not)
######## allOf
Class Name | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[_0](#_0) | str,  | str,  |  |

######### _0

######### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
str,  | str,  |  |

## Return Types

Code | Class | Description
------------- | ------------- | -------------
n/a | api_client.ApiResponseWithoutDeserialization | When skip_deserialization is True this response is returned
200 | [ResponseFor200.response_cls](#response_200response_cls) | success, multiple content types


### <a id="response_200description" >ResponseFor200.description</a>
success, multiple content types

### <a id="response_200response_cls" >ResponseFor200.response_cls</a>
Name | Type | Description  | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
response | urllib3.HTTPResponse | Raw response |
[body](#response_200content) | typing.Union[[ResponseFor200.content.application_json.schema](#response_200contentapplication_jsonschema), [ResponseFor200.content.multipart_form_data.schema](#response_200contentmultipart_form_dataschema), ] |  |
headers | Unset | headers were not defined |

#### <a id="response_200content" >ResponseFor200.content</a>

##### <a id="response_200contentapplication_jsonschema" >ResponseFor200.content.application_json.schema</a>

##### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader,  | frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO |  |

###### Composed Schemas (allOf/anyOf/oneOf/not)
###### allOf
Class Name | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[_0](#_0) | str,  | str,  |  |

####### _0

####### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
str,  | str,  |  |

##### <a id="response_200contentmultipart_form_dataschema" >ResponseFor200.content.multipart_form_data.schema</a>

##### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict,  | frozendict.frozendict,  |  |

###### Dictionary Keys
Key | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
**someProp** | [dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader, ](#someProp) | [frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO](#someProp) |  | [optional]
**any_string_name** | dict, frozendict.frozendict, list, tuple, decimal.Decimal, float, int, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, bool, None, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader, schemas.Schema | frozendict.frozendict, tuple, decimal.Decimal, str, bytes, BoolClass, NoneClass, FileIO | any string name can be used but the value must be the correct type | [optional]

####### someProp

####### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
dict, frozendict.frozendict, str, datetime.date, datetime.datetime, uuid.UUID, int, float, decimal.Decimal, bool, None, list, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO, io.BufferedReader,  | frozendict.frozendict, str, decimal.Decimal, BoolClass, NoneClass, tuple, bytes, io.FileIO |  |

######## Composed Schemas (allOf/anyOf/oneOf/not)
######## allOf
Class Name | Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------- | ------------- | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
[_0](#_0) | str,  | str,  |  |

######### _0

######### Schema Type Info
Input Type | Accessed Type | Description | Notes
------------ | ------------- | ------------- | -------------
str,  | str,  |  |

[[Back to top]](#top) [[Back to API]](../FakeApi.md) [[Back to Endpoints]](../../../../README.md#Endpoints) [[Back to README]](../../../../README.md)
```

Is it possible to generate levels of headers deeper than h6?
What are some possible solutions to render this deep content here?
Some added context is that this content is rendered to a readme file using [jknack handlebars](https://github.com/jknack/handlebars.java) and I have a headerSize template variable to store the anchor string like `####` so I could check its length and add conditional logic based on the answer.

Solutions that come to mind are:

1. limit header sizes to h6 max
2. limit header sizes to h8 max if it works, and treat h7 and h8 as special cases
3. use indentation with bulleted lists or some other indentation method to render sections rather than header sizes
4. switch over to bulleted lists when the h6 or h8 max is hit
5. limit to h6 and use `role=heading and aria-level=7-9` property per [How can I make new heading tag numbers, such as h7, h8, etc.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14908463/how-can-i-make-new-heading-tag-numbers-such-as-h7-h8-etc)
6. switch over to bulleted lists at definition under `### <a id="response_200response_cls" >ResponseFor200.response_cls</a>`

#### Update

I am going with a solution where my max heading level is h6. Schemas are accumulated and rendered at the same level even if they have deep levels of inlining. This prevents the heading depth from going deeper than h6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML has traditionally been limited to 6 levels of numbered headings (`h1` through `h6`) and Markdown is tied very closely to HTML.  In general, anything that renders to HTML is probably going to have some difficulty with extremely deeply nested headers for that reason.

You're probably going to achieve a better result if you use a different structure in your Markdown if your goal is HTML (like when something's rendered on GitHub).  If you were using a different document format that rendered differently (say, AsciiDoc converted to PDF via DocBook), then deeply nested headers would be less of a problem, but for HTML, a different structure will work best.

I might suggest instead defining a sample text document (e.g., a code block) that shows its structure and then defining each element in that structure at the same level.  That would be easier to view and read for the user, since they'd have a better context of the overall data format, and it would avoid the extremely deep nesting.  You can see an example of that in [some of GitHub's REST API documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/repos/contents?apiVersion=2022-11-28).

Comment: Are you talking about the code block samples on the right of that page?
That page only has two levels of heading depth and describes parameters under the deepest level of heading depth

Comment: Yes, I'm proposing an approach where you describe your protocol with a code block like on the right of that page and then define the values all at once in a table, like in the “Parameters” sections on that page.

Comment: My depth of nested data is deeper than they have and describing each block can be complicated. For example one has
Arguments.query_params
Arguments.path_params
each of those can have keys with the same value.
Arguments.query_params.someKey.schema then has a json schema which can have n levels of inline schema definition. The best approach that I have right now is, once a schema is reached, any deeper definitions are markdown inline indented lists.

Comment: It is working here: https://github.com/openapi-json-schema-tools/openapi-json-schema-generator/blob/v2_documentation_improvements/samples/openapi3/client/petstore/python/docs/apis/tags/fake_api/inline_composition.md#RequestQueryParametersParams
And I will need to add a solution that keeps anchor linking working from outer to inner definitions.

Comment: Okay, I would propose that you use `query_params.foo` and `path_params.foo`, or some other approach to describe it.  I would not use that tool, because it's extremely complex and hard to read, and not the kind of documentation I would want to use.  Ultimately, how you structure your text is up to you, but having lots of deeply nested text is not helpful for readability and it doesn't render well in HTML.

Comment: Removing the arguments layer of header only saves one header level. It does not solve the problem that inline schemas can be of depth n.
Also responses have similar complex structures at
- 200Resonse.content.application_json.schema
- 200Resonse.content.application_xml.schema
- 2XXResonse.content.application_json.schema

Comment: Don't nest your schema descriptions.  Describe a component of your schema at a time, and list all components at the same level.  If you need to refer to a nested schema component, link to it instead of describing it inline at a level below.

Comment: Food for thought, let me think about how I could do that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251936/discussion-between-spacether-and-bk2204).