# R markdown produces tabs called undefined when deeply nested

Tags: r, r-markdown, markdown

I have been frequently bumping into an issue where R markdown seems to produce tabs with the title "undefined" with code similar to the syntax below. Is there a way to have it produce normal tab names while deeply nested or is 6 #'s the limit?

````
```{r test, results='asis'}
for(dog in c('chowchow', 'poodle', 'husky')){
  cat("\n\n### ", dog, " {.tabset} \n")
  for(bird in c('parrot', 'chickadee', 'sparrow')){
    cat("\n\n#### ", bird, " {.tabset} \n")
    for(toothpaste in c('crest', 'colgate', 'target brand')){
      cat("\n\n##### ", toothpaste, " {.tabset} \n")
      for(language in c('R', 'Py', 'C')){
        cat("\n\n###### ", language, " {.tabset} \n")
        for(city in c('Boston', 'Minneapolis', 'Fairview')){
          cat("\n\n####### ", city, " {.tabset} \n")
          for(state in c('Ohio', 'Mississippi', 'New York')){
            cat("\n\n######## ", state, " {.tabset} \n")
            for(car in c('Toyota', 'Subaru', 'Ford')){
              cat("\n\n######### ", car, " {.tabset} \n")
              for(truck in c('El Derado', 'Jeep', 'Chevy')){
                cat("\n\n########## ", truck, " {.tabset} \n")
                for(icecream in c('Mint', 'Chocolate', 'Vanilla')){
                  cat("\n\n########### ", icecream, " \n")
                    cat("Hi")
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```
````

More information:

R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01)

2022.02.0+443 Prairie Trillium

pandoc 2.17.1.1

knitr 1.41

rmarkdown 2.19

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to use header levels higher than h6 in github markdown? What solutions allowing deeper levels of heading?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75453269/is-it-possible-to-use-header-levels-higher-than-h6-in-github-markdown-what-solu)